What's going on with these Steam updates that have small downloads but HUGE patching stages?
For the last year or two, I've noticed that some games on Steam have small download sizes but patches (disk-writes) that are significantly bigger. For example, this World of Warships patch - 1gb download and 44gb patch;

So my question is, what exactly is going on here? I can't believe that Steam implements a technology with over 40:1 compretion ratio. I've just had an SSD from a well-known brand fail after only a year in my build, and I can't help but think these ludicrous updates might have something to do with it, since it was my games bulk-storage drive.
Just curious about what's causing this because it seems somewhat new, at least to me. Any insight appreciated.

Duplicate of https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/402168/what-is-happening-when-steam-downloads-a-little-but-modifies-a-lot?rq=1 I believe.  This external page may also provide some insight.
